# Do Solidity functions time out?

Tags: contract-design, oracles, timers

I have a design where contract A is calling contract B, which then calls Oraclize a few times, and then sends the results back to contract A. The Oraclize calls could end up taking upwards of 30 minutes in certain cases.

Can I have contract B send the result back to contract A via a return value to the initial function call, even if it takes 30+ minutes to evaluate? Or do I have to use a callback function?

In other words, do Solidity functions time out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in B that request the oraclize query will finish after making the query. Oraclize will call the callback function later. When that happens, the callback in B needs to implement the steps to send the response to A.

Comment: To play devil's advocate, beware that in certain instances, namely due to an ugly block re-org, an Oraclize callback may in fact re-sorted EARLIER than the actual query it resulted from. So beware of that scenario and design contracts with that in mind.